# Detection circuit using optocoupler

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, analog

I am trying to find the most convenient circuit using only one optocoupler as seen in photo. There are two simple fans. If either of fans has fault signal, I need to detect error signal (or logic). Both fans need to stop after fault signal.

How can I modify this circuit? I want a fault signal when only one fan has fault.

*Fan has 3 pin, fault pin is low, when the fans has no fault*.[image]

Answer (score 1):

When one of the faults (*Fault 1* / *Fault 2*) occur (or both together), *detection* goes **Low**. Otherwise **High**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to construct an OR gate with just diodes:

[image]

It comes from this video:

*Diode Logic Gates - OR, NOR, AND, & NAND* - The Organic Chemistry Tutor

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lqwSaIDm2g

As the title implies, the video has designs for other logic gates.

Comment: But opto has only one diode and I want use only one opto, that's trick.

Comment: D1 and D2 are just plain diodes like 1N4148s. The LED on the right is your opto-coupler.